# Multi row insert using stored procedure in php

Tags: php, mysqli

As per my project requirement I have multiple records to insert in table.

And I am using a stored procedure so ... i.e. 700 records then loop iterate 700 time and procedure call 700 time. so it take too much load.

For that I have tried:

Stored procedure:

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tmp (`std`,`fees`) VALUES (str1);
END
```

Code:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($keys);$i++){
    if($i == (count($keys)-1)){
        $str .= "$std,$fees";
    } else {
        $str .= "$std, $fees),(";
    }   
}

include("../admin/conn.php");
$insert_stud_sql = mysqli_query($con, "CALL insertStudd($str)");
```

After complete the loop my str values like the following

```
12,25000),(8,15000),(4,12000
```

So, in procedure my query will become

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tmp (`std`,`fees`) VALUES (12,25000),(8,15000),(4,12000);
END
```

After all the process... I will not get proper result. I means data is not inserted into table.

If there any solution or alternate then please help me...

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error here, you missed closing quotes.

```
$str .= "$std,$fees";
```

also just make sure that you have already declare variable `$str` as `$str="";`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

**PHP code**

```
for($i=0;$i<count($keys);$i++){
 $str.="(".$std.",".$fees."),";
}
$str="values ".rtrim($str, ",");
```

this will output something like `values (12,25000),(8,15000),(4,12000)`

**SP**

```
BEGIN
set @query= CONCAT('INSERT INTO tmp (`std`,`fees`)',str1);
PREPARE dynamic_statement FROM @query;
EXECUTE dynamic_statement;
END
```

Now execute `$insert_stud_sql = mysqli_query($con, "CALL insertStudd($str)");` this will solve your problem.